# Mediaelement volume control is invisible on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

When using mediaelement.js on http://hanselminutes.com, the volume button is invisible on IE8. It seems that perhaps it's being covered up by the other audio controls being too wide? Oddly, if you click in the area that it should be, it's kind of there, although too far left. The volume icon never shows up.

[image: Invisible Volume control with MediaElementJS on IE8]

Comment: +1: Good question, well posed. Frakking refreshing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Internet Explorer 8(.0.7600.16385). But worse: The audio won't even play. (Message: Unspecified error.)

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about mediaelement.js but if you add the following to the bottom of your hanselminutes.css it appears to fix it:

```
.mejs-time-rail{
  max-width: 370px;
}

.mejs-time-total {
  max-width: 348px;
}
```